# FileNotFoundError mentions file name not in use anywhere

Tags: python, json

I want to extract data from some json files in a folder named jfiles.
The program is named jfileexp.py

No such file name json_files is present in my Finder or in code.
I saved the program with the updated name jfiles in the code and no file with that name exists anymore
How can this happen ?

> error : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/json_files'

```
import os

import json

os.chdir("/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/jfiles")

print(os.getcwd())

f = open ("1697006884_00033002_0000.json")
data1=json.loads(f)

for i in data:

    print(i)

f.close()
```

Tried editing os.getcwd and os.chdir out and got this new code

```py
import os
import json


f = open ("/User/arjunbakshi/Downloads/jfiles/1697006884_00033002_0000.json")

data1=json.loads(f)

for i in data:
    print(i)

f.close()
```

got the same error as in comments:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/arjunbakshi/jfileexp.py", line 2, in  if name == 'main': File "/Users/arjunbakshi/json.py", line 3, in  os.chdir("/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/json_files") builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/json_files' –

Comment: You'll need to post your entire code, or even better: a minimal reproducible example.... (probably you have `json_files` somewhere in your python code wrongly escaped or something..

Comment: I attached an imgur link right at the top. 
This is my first time using stack overflow and the attached photo keeps turning into a link and I can;'t figure out how to keep it to a link
Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
please do not post images of code.

Comment: edited the code into the question.
Also how do you get code into that grey box..
I tried using ''' but it didn't work

Comment: Please show the full traceback to your error too. I'm almost certain you're not running the file you think you're running...

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/arjunbakshi/jfileexp.py", line 2, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':
  File "/Users/arjunbakshi/json.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.chdir("/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/json_files")
builtins.FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/arjunbakshi/Downloads/json_files'

Comment: If you have a file called `json.py` in your directory, then `import json` is running that file instead of importing the Python JSON library. You should change the name of your `json.py` because this will cause all kind of problems.

Comment: Hi, there was json.py file on my Mac somewhere but not in the directory. Deleted it and now the code's working. But I still can't figure out why this out-of-directory file was impacting code when the working directory was set to Downloads only.
Thank you for your help !

Comment: What happened was: (1) Your fileexp.py executed `import json`. (2) Because you had a file called json.py, the result was to import that file, not the json module. (3) That json.py file contained the line `os.chdir(" ... /json_files")`, so the working directory got changed.

Comment: (The traceback you posted earlier proves that code in "/Users/arjunbakshi/json.py" was being executed.)

Comment: @slothrop you should post and answer, so that this question doesn't keep popping up unanswered. :)